# Redis not working in sinatra rake tasks

Tags: ruby, redis, rubygems, sinatra, rake

I would like to user Redis in my Sinatra app. Though I can access Redis instance in the console on local and remote (heroku), when I want to use it in a rake task, an error is triggered and I don t seem to get why is that.

app.rb:

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  configure do
    uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"])
    $redis = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
  end
end
```

config.ru:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require './app'
run MyApp
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'redis'
```

Rakefile.rb

```
desc 'Try Redis'
  task :try_redis do
  puts $redis.set("try", 0)
end
```

> rake aborted! NoMethodError: undefined method `set' for nil:NilClass

I am not really used to Sinatra, and nothing looks particularly wrong to me. I do not understand why my global variable $redis would not be accessible from everywhere in my app...

If you can enlighten me, thank you by advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not understand why my global variable $redis would not be
>   accessible from everywhere in my app

Your `rake` task is not related to your app. The `$redis` variable available only when you run `sinatra` server and not available when you run your rake task. The `rake` task run in own *thread*.

Comment: Thank you, I am still a bit confused about that("Your rake task is not related to your app."), but I just have to move the connexion to Redis into the rake task and it works fine. Your answer helped me to move forward, thank you very much!

Comment: _Your rake task is not related to your app._ I mean on the code level, your server and a rake task not connected,  it's a different thread.

Comment: open two `irb` session, and assign `$foo = 1` in one and try to `puts $foo` in other.

Comment: I see. They are 2 different threads, both should have a connexion to the same redis DB to be able to get the data. It makes sense. Thanks!